# Slices bars by column categories

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, visualization, plotly-python

I have a dataframe like this:

```
components               Servers    Paths    Endpoints    Security  Info
non-breaking-count        3455      123      989           134       432
breaking count            234       324      535           255       487
```

I have around `30` more columns after `Info`.

What I wish to do is plot two bars, one for `non-breaking-count`, another one for `breaking-count`, and to slice the bars with different colors for every column. I was wondering about doing it in plotly, but not sure how this could be done.

Does anyone have any ideas on how can I visualize this, perhaps using another library, but plotly is preferred.

The expected output is something like this:
[image]

Instead of `day`, I need the color as all my `columns` and `Male` and `Female` will be Breaking and Non-Breaking, and the xaxis will be their `count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out a workaround, which involved changing my dataframe.There was a slight change in the original data which I put in the question, which I have changed now for reference.

```
import pandas as pd

# Reshape the DataFrame using melt
melted_df = pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars=['components'], value_vars=['non_breaking_count', 'breaking_count'])

melted_df.columns = ['Component', 'Type_of_Change', 'Count']

# Map the Type_of_Change values to 'Non_breaking' and 'Breaking'
melted_df['Type_of_Change'] = melted_df['Type_of_Change'].map({'non_breaking_count': 'Non_breaking', 'breaking_count': 'Breaking'})

melted_df.sort_values(by=['Component', 'Type_of_Change'], inplace=True)
melted_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
melted_df
```

After the transformation, I was able to use the default plotly code for horizontal bar charts.